# Automating VSIX deployment to Visual Studio Galleries

Tags: visual-studio, build-automation, visual-studio-extensions

We would like to automate the upload of Visual Studio Extensions that we have written to the Visual Studio Gallery.

We currently use a combination of CruiseControl.Net, Msbuild files and Powershell scripts to automate the deployment of all the bits and pieces of our framework.

However we would like to automate the deployment of the development tools that we have created to the Visual Studio Gallery.

These tools are built using Visual Studio 2012.

Thanks for any helpful advice or pointers.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to do this with Canopy and FAKE. I just did it in https://github.com/fsprojects/Paket.VisualStudio/blob/master/build.fsx#L177

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no good way to do this.  There is no publicly exposed API for uploading extensions.  The only way I'm aware of is to create an instance of a web browser and simply automate the process of filling out the forms and navigating through the menus.

Comment: This may not be possible for uploading your VSIX to the official Visual Studio Extension Gallery, but it is definitely possible if you are publishing to a custom, private extension gallery (essentially just a network share), as we have automated this at my company.